# How can I get the position right and bottom in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to get the `right` and `bottom` position of the green box relative to the blue box
I want the result, which is the `bottom` and `right` position, to be printed on the `console`.

I do not know how I can do this, please help us, thanks

*I put my code link at the bottom*

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-bassi-nxi609?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm using all offsets (which is related to the parent box) within `useEffect` to get current element's position

```
useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById("child");
    console.log({
      top: element.offsetTop,
      right:
        element.parentElement.offsetWidth -
        (element.offsetLeft + element.offsetWidth),
      bottom:
        element.parentElement.offsetHeight -
        (element.offsetLeft + element.offsetHeight),
      left: element.offsetLeft
    });
  }, []);
```

You can check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-sutherland-hn6zxv?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: you might want to add `window.scrollY `to the `rect.bottom` value (since the rect is in screen space you might want to get the page location instead.

Comment: reason being, is because if you scroll the page then the rect bottom would be relative to the absoulte value...

Comment: Oh might be, but I think this is sufficient for his case @DeanVanGreunen

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work properly. When we move away from the left, the right should also be close to zero, but when it is printed on the console, the number of the right position is larger, while when we are closer to the right, the number should be smaller. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Let's me try to adjust it again to see the actual X and Y

Comment: When the left position is zero, the right position is 309.5. For example, change the left position from 0 to 100. We see that the right position also increases, and this is not true. When it increases from the left, it should also decrease from the right.

Comment: Could you find a way?

Comment: You want to have a relative position with blue box (not window), right? @Amir93

Comment: Yes, I want to always have the distance between the green box and the blue box by changing the size and position of the green box.

Comment: Updated my code in the answer and this sandbox too https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-sutherland-hn6zxv?file=/src/App.js @Amir93

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-noether-0ckk0r?file=/src/App.js This should work.

EDIT: I added logic to show how it calculates the offsets.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work properly and does not give us a new position by changing the position of the box

Comment: I updated the sandbox, check if it works better now, move mouse inside the container to see how it handles the calculations.